# Sorting xml by attribute in scala

Tags: xml, scala, sorting

Can i use scala.xml sortby or sortwith to sort xml by attribute.

For example:

```
<x>
  <y a=b/>
  <y a=a/>
</x>
```

Sortibg by @a will give:

```
<x>
  <y a=a/>
  <y a=b/>
</x>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way how to sort by the "a" attribute:

```
val xml = <x>
  <y a="b"/>
  <y a="c"/>
  <y a="a"/>
</x>

val updatedXml = xml.copy(child = (xml \ "y").sortBy(x => (x \ "@a").text)

val printer = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
println(printer.format(updatedXml))
```

which will print

```
<x>
  <y a="a"/>
  <y a="b"/>
  <y a="c"/>
</x>
```